# pillowのインポートができない: DLL load failed: 指定されたモジュールが見つかりません。

Tags: python

よろしくお願いします。

https://qiita.com/duonys/items/c941bc2818abe5cc1da7 のコードを実行していたのですが，

```
from PIL import Image
```

が通りませんでした。

PIL，pillowについて調べ，pillowの再インストールも試しましたが，エラーは回復しませんでした。
どのようにして対処すれば良いでしょうか？

**エラーコード**

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-46c5d2d71ab9> in <module>()
      3 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      4 from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
----> 5 from PIL import Image
      6 get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in <module>()
     56     # Also note that Image.core is not a publicly documented interface,
     57     # and should be considered private and subject to change.
---> 58     from . import _imaging as core
     59     if PILLOW_VERSION != getattr(core, 'PILLOW_VERSION', None):
     60         raise ImportError("The _imaging extension was built for another "

ImportError: DLL load failed: 指定されたモジュールが見つかりません。
```

Anaconda5.1を使用しており，インストールされているpillowのヴァージョンは5.0.0です。

---

追記

```
python --version
Python 3.6.4 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

です

---

追記

OSはWindows10です

また，basemapのインストールは上記リンクの通りではうまくいかなかったので，

[https://pyjbooks.github.io/py4science/install_pkgs.htmlの](https://pyjbooks.github.io/py4science/install_pkgs.html%E3%81%AE)

> 具体的には、以下の2つのインストールコマンドを実行します。「-c conda-forge」は、パッケージを「conda-forge」から取得してくる ことを意味します。2つ目のコマンドでは、詳細な精度の高い地図データをインストールしています。

```
> conda install -c conda-forge basemap=1.0.8.dev0
> conda install -c conda-forge basemap-data-hires
```

> これらを実行するだけで、インストール完了です。ただし、上記のコマンドで「1.0.8.dev0」とあるところは、 適宜最新のバージョンを指定するといいでしょう。最新のバージョンは、ここ で確認できます。
>   なお、basemapインストールの際に、conda自体のバージョンが古いものに変わってしまう場合があります。 他のパッケージの管理に影響すると考えられる場合は、次のようにしてcondaのバージョンを戻してしまいましょう。

```
> conda update conda
```

> これでcondaのバージョンを元に戻しても、basemapの利用上はなんら問題ありません。

を参考にしました（あまり関係はないと思いますが。。。）

Comment: `python --version` の結果も追記して頂けませんか？

Comment: 情報不足でした，すみません。追記しました

Comment: ありがとうございます。こちらの環境では再現できず、`import` が成功しました (Ubuntu 17.10, Python 3.6.4 (anaconda 5.1.0 py36_2, conda 4.5.0 py36_0), Pillow 5.0.0 py36h3deb7b8_0)。おそらく本家の[この質問](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48328838/5989200)と同じ内容だと思うのですが、本家にも現状回答がありませんね……。

Comment: 直接の解決ではなく、また、OS もライブラリ・バージョンも異なりますが、Pillow 5.0.0 やその他依存パッケージのバージョンにこだわりが無いのであれば、ダウングレードすると問題が解決するかもしれません: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43264773/5989200

Comment: もし何かしら心当たりがあれば、関係しそうな環境情報を今少し追記して頂ければと思います。こちらで問題を再現できるかもしれません。

Comment: 検証いただき，ありがとうございます。プログラムの経験に乏しいため，追記した情報では十分ではないと思いますが，よろしくお願いします。

Comment: Windows 環境であるという情報が大きかったです（勝手に Mac や Linux だと思っていました）。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

この挙動は以前は Pillow と Anaconda Cloud のバグとして知られていましたが、2018 年 7 月現在、解決しています。

通常通り `conda update` すれば解決するはずです。解決しない場合、[こちらのコメント](https://github.com/conda-forge/pillow-feedstock/issues/45#issuecomment-383955861)のようにまっさらな仮想環境を作って試すことが助けになるかもしれません。

ここより下は、まだこのバグが直っていなかったときの記述です。

---

### 2018 年 3 月時点での回答

Windows 10, Python 3.6.4 Anaconda, Pillow 5.0.0 で同様のエラーが出ることが Pillow の issue トラッカーにも報告されており、2018 年 3 月 22 日現在解決していません。

一時的な解決法として、一旦 anaconda から pillow をアンインストールし、pip でインストールするとエラーが出なくなる、と報告されています。つまり、`conda uninstall pillow` をした後 `pip install pillow` をすると解決することがあるようです。あまり行儀は良くありませんが、ひとまず動くだけで良いならこれで直るかもしれません。

また、バグとして報告されているので暫く待っていると対応され、直るかもしれません。

このバグについての最新情報は、以下の issue をご覧ください。
https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/2945

Comment: 丁寧なコメントありがとうございます。一時的な解決策として提案してくださった方法を試してみました。`conda uninstall pillow`をした後 `pip install pillow` をし，`python -c "from PIL import Image"`を試したところ，エラーなく通りました。しかし，`conda uninstall pillow`でアンインストールされたanaconda-navigatorを`conda install anaconda-navigator`で再インストールする際に，pillow 5.0.0-py36h0738816_0が同時にインストールされてしまいました。その後は再びエラーが起るようになりました。公式の対応を待ってみます。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem, but this resolved it
I think the last cash remains.
Add the option `--no-cache-dir` to disable caching, and use the option `-I, - ignore-installed` to re-install module.

```
pip --no-cache-dir install -I [module]
```

example

```
pip --no-cache-dir install -I pillow
pip --no-cache-dir install -I PIL
```

---

### 和訳

私も同じ問題に出会いましたが、以下の方法で解決しました。おそらくキャッシュが残っていたのだと思います。

`--no-cache-dir` オプションをつけてキャッシュを無効化し、`-I, -ignore-installed` でモジュールを再インストールします。

```
pip --no-cache-dir install -I [module]
```

例

```
pip --no-cache-dir install -I pillow
pip --no-cache-dir install -I PIL
```

Comment: もしあなたが日本語話者の場合、次から質問や回答は日本語でお願いいたします。 FYI: [スタック・オーバーフロー 多言語版：制限なく、遅れなく、包括的なものを、あなたの母国語で](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2825/) , [日本語が読み書きできる方へ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2314/can-i-ask-questions-in-english-%E8%8B%B1%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%A7%E8%B3%AA%E5%95%8F%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%82%82%E3%81%84%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B/2315#2315)